# How to use google translation API on Android?

Tags: android, google-translate

I am trying to use the google translate API in an an andriod app. Unfortunately I can not find a reasonable way to do this as google cloud java client does not currently support andriod!

What is the preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see this [link](https://github.com/sibaihm/google-translate/blob/master/src/com/sibaihm/googletranslate/googletranslate.java)

**How it works?**

It takes three parameters, the text which will be translated, the source language and the target language. It performs the translation in background and returns a string with the result

**Features**

- Translating text using Google Cloud Translation API
- Only one short class thus Easy to use and understand

**َAn Example:**

```
GoogleTranslate googleTranslate = new GoogleTranslate();
// Perform the translation by invoking the execute method, but first save the result in a String.
// The second parameter is the source language, the third is the terget language
String result = googleTranslate.execute("the text to be translated", "en", "de").get();
```

**UPDATE**:

Also checkout this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/translating-text-with-rest) and in [github](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client).

Hope it will be help you.

Comment: can you clearly told me what you want to do , speech to text ,text to speech ,or sentence transalation etc.

Comment: is this api is free or paid??

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud Translation API is exposed as a REST API, as shown in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart), so you can just use it with your favourite Android HTTP library.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try out [Phrase](https://github.com/KingsMentor/Phrase)
Phrase provides a way to translate user-generated content to the desired target language using different translation engines or options of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

The `sourceList` contains a list of words or phrases to be translated.
If `sourceLanguage` is NULL, then Google itself will determine the source of the language. The task returns a List of translated words/phrases.

```
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:2.16.0'
```

I wrote this code just as an example, you can use it however you like.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("cat");
list.add("dog");
list.add("fish");
list.add("apple");
new TranslateAsyncTask(list, null, "ua").execute();
```

Use your API key.

```
public class TranslateAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

private final String TAG = TranslateAsyncTask.class.getName();
private final String API_KEY = "YOUR API KEY";

private List<String> sourceList = new ArrayList<>();
private String sourceLanguage;
private String targetLanguage;

public TranslateAsyncTask(List<String> list, String source, String target) {
   this.sourceList = list;
   this.sourceLanguage = source;
   this.targetLanguage = target;
}

@Override
protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "from " + this.sourceLanguage
                + "->" + this.targetLanguage
                + " : text: " + this.sourceList.toString());

        // Objects needed for the translate object
        NetHttpTransport netHttpTransport   = new NetHttpTransport();
        JacksonFactory jacksonFactory       = new JacksonFactory();
        Translate translate = new Translate.Builder(netHttpTransport, jacksonFactory, null).build();
        
        Translate.Translations.List listToTranslate
                = translate
                .new Translations()
                .list(sourceList, targetLanguage)
                .setKey(API_KEY);

        // If sourceLanguage == null then  the language detects automatically
        if (sourceLanguage != null) listToTranslate.setSource(sourceLanguage);

        // Executing the translation and saving the response in the response object
        TranslationsListResponse response = listToTranslate.execute();
        
        List<TranslationsResource> list = response.getTranslations();
        Log.i(TAG, "result list size: " + list.size());
        for (TranslationsResource resource : list) {
            Log.i(TAG, "resource: " + resource.getTranslatedText());
            resultList.add(resource.getTranslatedText());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }

    return resultList;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
    Log.w(TAG, "RESULT: " + result.toString());
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

}
```